# Tumblr API in PHP File structure

Tags: php, tumblr

I'm trying to use the Tumblr API (PHP) and I cant seem to get all the required files to load correctly.

The Tumblr API can be found here: https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr.php

First thing I found out is that it doesnt include OAuth, so after some searching I found the files on github and uploaded them to my server.

Now it's saying it needs Guzzle.  OK, got that uploaded now, but I cant seem to get all the Guzzle files to load up...  Example error message:

`Interface 'Guzzle\Common\HasDispatcherInterface' not found in /TumblrTest/Guzzle/Common/AbstractHasDispatcher.php`

There's a `HasDispatcherInterface.php` file in that path...

Do the files need to be in a special order?  I tried putting all .php files into a folder, and then using `require_once` I searched for all *.php files in that folder, but that didnt work...

Sorry for a super noob question, any help would be greatly appriciated!  Let me know if there's any other info i need to give to help answer this question!

-D

UPDATE:  I still have no idea how the above works, but I found a way around it...  I actually think it might be easier then figuring the above out!!  The following PHP code does what i need it to do, which is grab the posts of the provided user:

```
$apikey = **[insert api key here]**;
$limit = $_POST['limit'];
$user = $_POST['user'];
$tumblr=$user . ".tumblr.com";
$apidata = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/$tumblr/posts/photo?api_key=$apikey&limit=$limit"));
$mypostsdata = $apidata->response->posts;
$myposts = array();
$j = 0;
foreach($mypostsdata as $postdata) {
    $post["photo_url"] = $postdata->photos[0]->original_size->url;
    $post["width"] = $postdata->photos[0]->original_size->width;
    $post["height"] = $postdata->photos[0]->original_size->height;
    $myposts[$j] = $post;
    $j++;
}
echo json_encode($myposts);
```

For some reason I cant get it to pull a list of people i'm following and then get their posts, but oh well...

Comment: I'm having similar difficulties with using the PHP library simply because I have no idea how to use `composer-php` and the documentation is confusing. I'm trying to run it on a shared space host (e.g. Bluehost) and I absolutely cannot get composer or the `phar` calls to work.

Comment: how can we get login a person to tumblr like facebook. and how to check that person is logged in or not and then get its username or tumblrname.

Comment: Using composer is quite easy, if you follow the instructions at https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md to install it on your OS globally you can run composer install within the project root to install your dependencies for you. You'll find most PHP projects these days will be using composer so at some point you'll need to get the hang of it to make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

The tumblr.php Readme might be a bit confusing.

The package depends on other packages. All can be installed via composer.

Go to the http://getcomposer.org and read this carfully, if you are used to the concept, you will start rewriting all you classes to fit the composer dependency manager ;-)

to make it short:
install composer globally and
go into a blank directory and
type in your terminal

```
composer require tumblr/tumblr
```

you should get all the classes and the other projects in a dir called vendor.

before you do anything you need to require the autoload.php file. 
And check out the concept of namespaces in php.